# Adjust number of digits for small pvalue to be displayed in title of a plot using renderPlot in Shiny in R

Tags: r, plot, shiny, digits, p-value

In R one can use `options(digits=n)` to adjust the number of digits in the output value. However, this does not work in Shiny, and `sprintf()` does not work with very low numbers either since it would only display zeros. So, how could i obtain in Shiny something like

```
options(digits = 4)
```

> p.val$p.value
> [1] 3.724e-23

So that i could use it in the title of the plot in renderPlot?

Comment: Could you share a mini app and show what has failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing `options`, we can simply use `signif` to set our required number of digits. The following mini app can be modified as necessary to work for plot titles.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           
           numericInput(
             "hello_options",
             label = "Number",
             value = 3.145677177118
           )),
    
    column(6, 
           numericInput("digits",
                        label = "Digits",
                        value = 4
                        )
           )
  ),
  
  
  textOutput("out_text")

)

server <- function(input, output, server){
    output$out_text <- renderText(
      signif(input$hello_options, digits = input$digits)
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you want to `format` to scientific, then change your server to this. Note however that this gives you characters that should be converted back.

```
server <- function(input, output, server){
    output$out_text <- renderText(
      format(signif(input$hello_options, digits = input$digits),
             scientific = TRUE)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not manage to make a miniapp so fast... By scientific, do you mean the same ouput format as I showed in the question? I tried `signif()` and used it in the `main` argument of `boxplot()` and did not change the initial format, i.e. 3.724e-23 format.

Comment: Yes, I think the same output as in your question. It seems the output between `signif` and `format` is the same anyway so `format` is probably unnecessary (only that it is more commonly used).